# Cannot login after installing. Database shows hashed password:

Tags: php, hash, codeigniter-2

Let me preface this by saying I am not the best with writing php.  I also did not write the following code, but am looking for some guidance on what I am missing as far as what is going on in the bigger process here.

After the initial install of a [free ticketing software](http://getvivekv.bitbucket.org/fuse/download.html#) which utilizes CodeIgniter and twitter-Bootstrap frameworks, the database sets up a default admin account with my admin email and, what should be, a default password of admin:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblstaffs` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `hash` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblstaffs`
--

INSERT INTO `tblstaffs` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `password`, `admin`, `hash`) VALUES
(1, 'Admin', 'Admin', 'admin@admin.com', '08gv6gemSKxv09EImCsPLO94Nje6ZVAlFnuc13kohFwvC0kh/ESFEn1lEwL9bbSbrlym/UrO6wM9p0CGnjJHzg==', 1, '');
```

I see this value:

```
08gv6gemSKxv09EImCsPLO94Nje6ZVAlFnuc13kohFwvC0kh/ESFEn1lEwL9bbSbrlym/UrO6wM9p0CGnjJHzg==
```

within the database as well.

Attempting to type in 'admin' as the password has no effect.  I assume I am possibly missing some php extension that is necessary?

```
            // Form validation success.

        $data['firstname'] = $this -> input -> post('firstname');
        $data['lastname'] = $this -> input -> post('lastname');
        $data['email'] = $this -> input -> post('email');
        $data['id'] = $this -> input -> post('id');

        if($this->input->post('password'))
            $data['password'] = $this->encrypt->encode($this -> input -> post('password'));

        $result = $this -> Admin -> EditStaff($data);

        if ($result == FALSE)
        {
            $status['statusmsg'] = "A user with the email already exists";
            $status['status'] = 0;
            echo json_encode($status);
        }
        else
        {
            $status['status'] = 1;
            echo json_encode($status);
```

Comment: Where do you type "admin" as the password ? in the html form you mean ? if so, you're probably hashing the password incorrectly, can you show us what the hash for "admin" becomes in your php form ?

Comment: Plus, Bootstrap has nothing to deal with the problem, as it is full PHP related.

Comment: It looks like the password might be being (reversibly) encrypted, rather than hashed, which wouldn't be good. What encryption key is set in your config file? (application/config/config.php; should be something like `$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";`...) Is it definitely the right one?

Comment: Thanks for the information guys and thank you for the upvote.  Much appreciated.  Missing mcrypt extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ticketing system uses CodeIgniter's Encryption library to encrypt its passwords (NB: this is a bad thing; it is reversible encryption, not a hash.)

CodeIgniter's Encryption library uses [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) if it's available, otherwise falls back to a less secure method of its own.

The password provided in the database script was definitely encrypted using mcrypt. I'm guessing what's going on is that you don't have the mcrypt module set up in your PHP installation.

There are a few possible options:

1. *Add the mcrypt extension to your PHP installation on your server first* and then log in using the email address that you've specified in tblstaffs, and the password "admin" (that *is* the correct password; I've reproduced your problem and checked.)
2. Don't install mcrypt, and use the password recovery procedure in the ticketing system to have it email a new password to the email address you've specified. This will replace the existing password with a new one using whichever encryption method is currently working. Obviously, you'll need to make sure the email address in tblstaffs is a valid one, and that outgoing mail is working on your PHP installation.
3. Manually update the encrypted password for the admin user in tblstaffs to one that's compatible with your non-mcrypt encryption. I believe "AmJUYVxsAzgBNQ==" is a value that might work for the password "admin".

Personally, though, I wouldn't advise using this ticketing system for anything that's going to be publicly available. Authentication systems should used salted one-way hashes, not reversible encryption.

Comment: Definitely missing mcrypt. (doh)  I'll be modifying this and using it internally so security shouldn't be a huge issue with this.  Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have an issue with encryption, change this line

```
if($this->input->post('password'))
            $data['password'] = $this->encrypt->encode($this -> input -> post('password'));
```

To something like this (to see what 'password' becomes after encryption)

```
if($this->input->post('password')){
    $data['password'] = $this->encrypt->encode($this -> input -> post('password'));
    echo "Password: $this->input->post('password')";
    echo "Encrypted password: $data['password']";
}
```

if it echoes something different than:

`08gv6gemSKxv09EImCsPLO94Nje6ZVAlFnuc13kohFwvC0kh/ESFEn1lEwL9bbSbrlym/UrO6wM9p0CGnjJHzg==`

this means you probably have a wrong encryption key in your code igniter confs, either that, or the actual string:

`08gv6gemSKxv09EImCsPLO94Nje6ZVAlFnuc13kohFwvC0kh/ESFEn1lEwL9bbSbrlym/UrO6wM9p0CGnjJHzg==`

isn't the correct encrypted key for the password 'admin' !